# how to fill image into canvas from fileupload control c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

I made a compress or resize the image on the client side with canvas, but I am wondering how to fill the image into canvas with a FileUpload control from c #.

then each took a picture of how that canvas cleaned first and then filled with the new picture?

this is my source:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        var canvas = document.getElementById("cc");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onload = function() {
            var W = img.width;
            var H = img.height;
            canvas.width = W;
            canvas.height = H;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            resample_hermite(canvas, W, H, 439, 222);
        }
        img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/8VsK7gS.png';        
    });

function resample_hermite(canvas, W, H, W2, H2) {
        var time1 = Date.now();
        W2 = Math.round(W2);
        H2 = Math.round(H2);
        var img = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, W, H);
        var img2 = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, W2, H2);
        var data = img.data;
        var data2 = img2.data;
        var ratio_w = W / W2;
        var ratio_h = H / H2;
        var ratio_w_half = Math.ceil(ratio_w / 2);
        var ratio_h_half = Math.ceil(ratio_h / 2);

        for (var j = 0; j < H2; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < W2; i++) {
                var x2 = (i + j * W2) * 4;
                var weight = 0;
                var weights = 0;
                var weights_alpha = 0;
                var gx_r = gx_g = gx_b = gx_a = 0;
                var center_y = (j + 0.5) * ratio_h;
                for (var yy = Math.floor(j * ratio_h); yy < (j + 1) * ratio_h; yy++) {
                    var dy = Math.abs(center_y - (yy + 0.5)) / ratio_h_half;
                    var center_x = (i + 0.5) * ratio_w;
                    var w0 = dy * dy //pre-calc part of w
                    for (var xx = Math.floor(i * ratio_w); xx < (i + 1) * ratio_w; xx++) {
                        var dx = Math.abs(center_x - (xx + 0.5)) / ratio_w_half;
                        var w = Math.sqrt(w0 + dx * dx);
                        if (w >= -1 && w <= 1) {
                            //hermite filter
                            weight = 2 * w * w * w - 3 * w * w + 1;
                            if (weight > 0) {
                                dx = 4 * (xx + yy * W);
                                //alpha
                                gx_a += weight * data[dx + 3];
                                weights_alpha += weight;
                                //colors
                                if (data[dx + 3] < 255)
                                    weight = weight * data[dx + 3] / 250;
                                gx_r += weight * data[dx];
                                gx_g += weight * data[dx + 1];
                                gx_b += weight * data[dx + 2];
                                weights += weight;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                data2[x2] = gx_r / weights;
                data2[x2 + 1] = gx_g / weights;
                data2[x2 + 2] = gx_b / weights;
                data2[x2 + 3] = gx_a / weights_alpha;
            }
        }
        console.log("hermite = " + (Math.round(Date.now() - time1) / 1000) + " s");
        canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, Math.max(W, W2), Math.max(H, H2));
        canvas.width = W2;
        canvas.height = H2;
        canvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(img2, 0, 0);
    }
```

thanks for all your help

Comment: When you need resize do you have the file uploaded at server? What is the event flow?

Comment: thanks for response, So, I tried to compress or resize the image on the client side and then upload the files that have been compressed to server.
is that possible?